# How do display a hex and decimal numerical value of a character in C

Tags: c

I wrote a program in which the user is prompted to input a character from the keyboard and using `else if()` statements the computer will tell the user what type of character it is.

For example:

> Enter a character from keyboard>
>   r
>   Selected character is a lower case letter

It works up until here. I want to know how to display the numerical and hexadecimal value of that character `'r'`. this is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d;
    int x;                              
    char key;

    printf(" Enter a character from the keyboard>");
    scanf(" %c",&key);

    if(key >= 48 && key <= 57)
    {
        printf(" Selected character is a Number\n");
        printf(" Numerical value selected character is:\n\n");
        printf(" Decimal\n\nHexadecimal\n\n");
        scanf(" %d %x",&d,&x); 
    }
    else if(key >= 65 && key <= 90)
    {
        printf(" Selected character is an Uppercase letter\n");
        printf(" Numerical value selected character is:\n\n");
        printf(" Decimal\n\nHexadecimal\n\n");
        scanf(" %d %x",&d,&x);
    }    
    else if(key >= 97 && key <= 122)
    {
        printf(" Selected character is a Lowercase letter\n");
        printf(" Numerical value selected character is:\n\n");
        printf(" Decimal\n\nHexadecimal\n\n");
        scanf(" %d %x",&d,&x);
    }    
    else if((key >= 0 && key <= 47)||(key >= 58 && key <= 64)
        ||(key >= 91 && key>=96)||(key >= 123 && key <= 127))
    {
        printf(" Selected character is a special character\n");
        printf(" Numerical value of selected character is:\n\n");
        printf(" Decimal\n\nHexadecimal\n\n");
        scanf(" %d %x",&d,&x);
    } 
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When I execute it, it doesn't give me the actual numerical value of a character.

Comment: What data types are `d` and `x` declared as? Please show more of your code, along with the output of the program. Are you using `scanf` when you mean to use `printf`?

Answer (score 0):

With your final "scanf," it looks like your trying to get more input from the console, when you actually want to be displaying the existing "key" value in varying representations. Try replacing your last two lines with the following:

```
    printf(" Decimal: %d\n\nHexadecimal: %#x\n\n", key, key);
```

This will cause the "key" value that you already captured to be presented in decimal (%d) and hexadecimal (%#x) format.

Comment: @user3314650: "it doesn't work!" is probably not what your compiler or output tells you. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: Ok never mind..it works i forgot to put in the placeholder %d and %x in the printf command!! Thank u soo much !! :)